# Simple helper method - Am I doing it right?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

New to Ruby and Rails.

I am developing a simple app for where you can register teams, players etc and it looks like this:

Team has_many Players
Players belongs_to Team

When I want to show the player in view(normal users):

```
<%= @player.name %> - <%= playerteam %>
```

and in the admin view it looks like this:

```
<% @players.each do |player| %>
    <tr>        
        <td><%= player.id %></td>   
        <td><%= player.name %></td>
        <td><%= playerteam(player) %></td>
        <td><%= owner(player) %></td>               
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

and the helper method:

```
def playerteam(player = nil)      
  if player != nil
    if player.team_id == nil
      return "No team"
    else
      @team = Team.find(player.team_id)
      return @team.name
    end
  else              
    if @player.team_id == nil
      return "No team"      
    else
      @team = Team.find(@player.team_id)
      return @team.name
     end
  end
end
```

It works but it is not pretty or "Ruby Sexy"

At first it was only used from the normal view but then when I wanted to use it from the admin-view also I had to add the parameter with a default value and the extra if-clause.

Are there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use a helper method at all. Helper Methods shouldn't be used to retrieve model data. That's what's the model is for.

you can do something like this:

normal users:

```
<%= @player.name %> - <%= player.team ? player.team.name : 'No Team' %>
```

admin:

```
<% @players.each do |player| %>
    <tr>        
        <td><%= player.id %></td>   
        <td><%= player.name %></td>
        <td><%= player.team ? player.team.name : 'No Team' %></td>
        <td><%= owner(player) %></td>               
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

You could probably do something similar with the `owner`-helper

to avoid the `? :`-if-else syntax in every view you can add this to your player model

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  def team_name
    team ? team.name : "No Team"
  end
end
```

Then you views look like this:

normal users:

```
<%= @player.name %> - <%= @player.team_name %>
```

admin:

```
<% @players.each do |player| %>
    <tr>        
        <td><%= player.id %></td>   
        <td><%= player.name %></td>
        <td><%= player.team_name %></td>
        <td><%= owner(player) %></td>               
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

IMHO: This would be much more "Rails Sexy" ;-)

Comment: Yeah, that worked like a charm and is very sexy. :) The only thing I had to change was <%= player.team_name %> to <%= @player.team_name %> Now I have to do this to my other helper-methods also.

Answer (score 0):

```
def playerteam(player = nil)      

    if (player || @player).team_id == nil
      return "No team"
    else
      @team = Team.find((player || @player).team_id)
      return @team.name
    end

end
```

Seems to be enough in your case. Or you can made the `(player || @player)` in your view

```
<% @players.each do |player| %>
    <tr>        
        <td><%= player.id %></td>   
        <td><%= player.name %></td>
        <td><%= playerteam((player || @player)) %></td>
        <td><%= owner(player) %></td>               
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

with helper simplest because you define all the time a player

```
def playerteam(player)      
    if player.team_id == nil
      return "No team"
    else
      @team = Team.find(player.team_id)
      return @team.name
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can just do:

```
def playerteam(player = @player)
  if player.team_id == nil
    return "No team"
  else
    @team = Team.find(player.team_id)
    return @team.name
  end
end
```

But you may also want to tidy your code up a little:

```
def playerteam(player = @player)
  if player.team
    return player.team.name
  else
    return "No team"
  end
end
```

If you do want to set `@team` to the player's team then I'd do it somewhere other than a helper method as it is very confusing to be setting attributes in a helper method. You are then relying on the helper method having been called to access `@team`.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely refactor that!

```
def playerteam(player = nil)      
  player ||= @player
  return "No team" if player.team_id.nil?
  Team.find(player.team_id).name
end
```